# Figure placement specifiers being written as text

Tags: floats, positioning

All I'm trying to do is add placement specifiers to my figures with eg.`[ht]`. Instead of using them as arguments, latex decides to literally write `[ht]` into the pdf as text.

So here is my sample latex:

```
\documentclass[usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.PNG}
\graphicspath{{./pics/}}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}


\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{cartoon}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{figure}


    \bibliography{Remote}
\end{document}
```

Then I get [image: pdf output]

The placement specifiers aren't being listened to!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the class documentation

> The LaTeX float placement commands `[htbp]` are intentionally
>   disabled. Layout of figures and tables will be adjusted by the
>   publisher during the production process, so authors should not concern
>   themselves with placement to avoid disappointment and wasted effort.

Ideally the optional argument would still be defined, and simply thrown away, but it seems that it's not implemented at all so you see some spurious text: you'll need to delete the positioning arguments.

Comment: I've reported this to the maintainer

Comment: Ah, Ok. I can see why they do that. But how do I stop the image from going behind text?

Comment: @Lucidnonsense I don't understand what you mean: the image you've posted looks like what I'd expect for some literal text then a picture.

Comment: @JosephWright A class released in 2015 that is plagued with `\rm`, `\it` and `\bf`. Also this should be reported.

Comment: The image shown here is from the minimal example latex, but in my actual report I need a large figure. When I put `width=\textwidth` it puts the figure behind the text. Other than that there is no difference between code here and my report.

Comment: Turns out that `*figure` in place of `figure` will do that job. Thanks anyway